# Настройка nginx для laravel

Tags: laravel, nginx, php

Добрый день, пытаюсь настроить laravel для nginx, ничего не выходит.

Конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name decoder.lan;
    root /var/www/decoder-now/public;

    index index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
    }

    location @php { ## Depending on your Nginx version, you might need to change this to location ~ \.php$

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location @handler {
      rewrite / /index.php;
    }

}
```

Получаемая ошибка (error.log) (в логах адресуемся к url: decoder.lan/address, но просто decoder.lan тоже не работает):

```
  2014/11/24 15:13:43 [crit] 14063#0: *10 stat() "/var/www/decoder-now/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: decoder.lan, request: "GET /address/ HTTP/1.1", host: "decoder.lan"
    2014/11/24 15:13:43 [crit] 14063#0: *10 stat() "/var/www/decoder-now/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: decoder.lan, request: "GET /address/ HTTP/1.1", host: "decoder.lan"
    2014/11/24 15:13:43 [crit] 14063#0: *10 stat() "/var/www/decoder-now/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: decoder.lan, request: "GET /address/ HTTP/1.1", host: "decoder.lan"
    2014/11/24 15:13:43 [crit] 14063#0: *10 stat() "/var/www/decoder-now/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: decoder.lan, request: "GET /address/ HTTP/1.1", host: "decoder.lan"
    2014/11/24 15:13:43 [crit] 14063#0: *10 stat() "/var/www/decoder-now/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: decoder.lan, request: "GET /address/ HTTP/1.1", host: "decoder.lan"
    2014/11/24 15:13:43 [crit] 14063#0: *10 stat() "/var/www/decoder-now/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: decoder.lan, request: "GET /address/ HTTP/1.1", host: "decoder.lan"
    2014/11/24 15:13:43 [crit] 14063#0: *10 stat() "/var/www/decoder-now/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: decoder.lan, request: "GET /address/ HTTP/1.1", host: "decoder.lan"
    2014/11/24 15:13:43 [crit] 14063#0: *10 stat() "/var/www/decoder-now/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: decoder.lan, request: "GET /address/ HTTP/1.1", host: "decoder.lan"
    2014/11/24 15:13:43 [crit] 14063#0: *10 stat() "/var/www/decoder-now/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: decoder.lan, request: "GET /address/ HTTP/1.1", host: "decoder.lan"
    2014/11/24 15:13:43 [crit] 14063#0: *10 stat() "/var/www/decoder-now/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: decoder.lan, request: "GET /address/ HTTP/1.1", host: "decoder.lan"
    2014/11/24 15:13:43 [error] 14063#0: *10 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while redirect to named location "@rewrite", client: 127.0.0.1, server: decoder.lan, request: "GET /address/ HTTP/1.1", host: "decoder.lan"
```

access.log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2014:15:13:43 +0300] "GET /address/ HTTP/1.1" 500 603 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 (x86_64)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36"
```

Сам пытался проверить если ли права у www-data на чтение, проверяю с помощью команды:

```
sudo -u www-data cat index.php
```

Файл открывается.

`www-data`, т.к. в `/ect/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` стоит:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

Ну и на последок, файлы:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data  www-data 2238 нояб. 17 19:01 favicon.ico
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data  www-data 1586 нояб. 17 19:01 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data  www-data 4096 нояб. 17 19:01 packages
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data  www-data   24 нояб. 17 19:01 robots.txt
```

Поменял права у index.php специально

На сервере также стоит апач, который, конечно же, сейчас выключен, соответственно 80 порт ссылается только на nginx.

**Обновление**

[[[[@smgladkovskiy](/users/24788/smgladkovskiy)](/users/24788/smgladkovskiy)](/users/24788/smgladkovskiy)](/users/24788/smgladkovskiy) спасибо, после того как я поменял конфиг, возникла проблема:

> 2014/11/24 18:37:37 [crit] 8388#0: *1
> stat() "/var/www/decoder-now/public/"
> failed (13: Permission denied),
> client: 127.0.0.1, server:
> decoder.lan, request: "GET /
> HTTP/1.1", host: "decoder.lan"
>
> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary
> script unknown" while reading response
> header from upstream, client:
> 127.0.0.1, server: decoder.lan, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:",
> host: "decoder.lan"

[[[[@smgladkovskiy](/users/24788/smgladkovskiy)](/users/24788/smgladkovskiy)](/users/24788/smgladkovskiy)](/users/24788/smgladkovskiy) пробовал менять на IP адрес с портом - не помогает. Смотрел при помощи `netstat -lnxp`, находит сокет - `var/run/php5-fpm.sock`.

Answer (score 4):

Рабочий пример:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name laravel-test.localhost;
    root /home/vagrant/stuff/laravel-test/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/laravel-test.localhost-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: @smgladkovskiy пробовал менять на IP адрес с портом - не помогает. смотрел при помощи `netstat -lnxp`, находит сокет - var/run/php5-fpm.sock

Comment: Конфиг сайта прописан в sites-available?
Директива SCRIPT_FILENAME в fastcgi_param как объявлена? Вообще, менялось ли что в конфигах nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Я пользуюсь [laravel-website-configs](https://github.com/daylerees/laravel-website-configs). Все грамотно прописано, с комментариями.

С помощью этих конфигов разворачиваю проекты на дропплетах Digital Ocean без всяких проблем + использую для локально разработки под Vagrant.

Comment: Прошу прощения в модераторов, помочь хочу, а оформление страдает.